# POST request in UWP not sending

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio, uwp

I writing app for UWP

I receive json from back end like this:

```
string url = "http://api.simplegames.com.ua/index.php/?wc_orders=all_orders";
{
    string jsonString;

    using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return jsonString;
}
```

I try to send POST request like this

```
OrdersList = new List<RootObject>(rootObjectData);
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://api.simplegames.com.ua");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("utf-8"));

    string endpoint = @"/post_from_local.php";

    try
    {
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(OrdersList), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(endpoint, content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine(jsonResponse);
            //do something with json response here
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //Could not connect to server
        //Use more specific exception handling, this is just an example
    }
}
```

But, Back end dev said that he see empty row, but data is not received.

Thank's for help. Where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
```

to:

```
var stream = httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url).Result;
```

Comment: Not works. I hink I understood where is my problem. My problem in async await. I try to send json via post request before it write to json variable

Comment: Exactly, that's why I thought this could solve the issue.

Comment: Okay. I rewrite like you said. but it seems it not fix issue

Comment: Wait, I will try one thing and write to you after that